Visual Puzzle: The ? Model
What 12 letter word is depicted below? Please explain your reasoning.


Hint:

 Count and divide

Stronger hint:

 DPPERM

Even stronger hint:

 Key:DaPePeElRoMo

Decisive hint

 The first column is 7 blocks high focus on what that could be referring too…


Just to add, even though the knowledge tag is present a lot of the knowledge required here is trivial…

Does this have something to do with the periodic table

Just out of curiosity how far has anyone got with this? Partial answers are welcomed

Haven't started, have no clue to where to start

rot13(V unir gur fnzr srryvat nf htthchtth. Va cnegvphyne, gur erpgnatyr sbezrq ol gur obggbz gjb ebjf naq gur guveq hagvy friragrragu pbyhzaf erzvaq zr bs gur ynagunavqrf cyhf yhgrgvhz naq npgvavqrf cyhf ynjerapvhz. Ohg gung'f nyy V tbg.) EDIT: Gung vf orpnhfr vg vf fvzvyne gb gur cerfragngvba bs gur crevbqvp gnoyr jurer gurl chg gur ynagunavqrf naq npgvavqrf orgjrra tebhc gjb naq sbhe.

@oAlt I don’t want to give it away but all I will say is that you are very close to being on the right track . But please I urge you to check the last hint!

My thoughts: rot13(Gur tevq fcyvgf vagb erpgnathyne frpgvbaf juvpu rnpu ercerfrag zrzoref bs n snzbhf tebhc. r.t. Gur pbyhza bs 7 vf gur QNlf bs gur jrrx, gur raq pbyhza bs 12 vf ZBaguf bs gur lrne (juvpu ortva jvgu gur yrggref va gur uvag). Jr nyfb unir gur CRevbqvp gnoyr ynagunavqrf naq npgvavqrf, naq cbffvoyl EBzna ahzrenyf, znlor gur sbhe RYrzragf, naq fbzrguvat ryfr ortvaavat jvgu CR. Cerfhznoyl jr pubbfr gur yrggref bs gur pbybherq barf nppbeqvatyl. Ubjrire, V'z trggvat gjb W'f sebz gur zbaguf (be whfg bar vs vg'f whfg orra birepyhrq) naq fgehttyvat gb fcryy nalguvat sebz gur bguref.)

@Stiv you got that far and the answer still hasn’t hit you yet lol you are sooo close

Well, I have an idea but it isn't 100% complete. Since it's been a while perhaps I should post a pretty-good-stab-at-it partial...

@stiv please do, the answer might even occur to you as you write it up

The answer is:

 The HELIOCENTRIC Model

The grid ...

 ... represents six groups: Two plus three vertical single-cell strips to the left and right and a 2×15 block in the centre. These groups are hinted at in hints 2 and 3. The groups are:

 7 Days of the week
 4 elements in Group 12 of the Periodic table
 15 lanthanides and 15 actinides in the Periodic table
 4 classical Elements
 7 Roman numerals
 12 Months of the year

The highlighted cells ...

 ... go into the ten boxes below the grid. It looks as if the boxes were made for letters, but they represent major bodies in our solar system:

    yellow (I): Sun  — Sunday
    grey: Mercury  — Mercury (Hg)
    gold: Venus  — the Roman numeral V*
    green: Earth — the classical element Earth
    red: Mars — March
    orange: Jupiter  — June and July**
    brown: Saturn  — Saturday
    medium blue: Uranus  — Uranium
    dark blue: Neptune  — Neptunium
    white (X): Pluto  — Plutonium

 The given Roman numbers (I) for sun and (X) for Pluto represent their positions in the solar system. (Perhaps the X for Pluto indicates that pluto isn't considered a proper planet anymore.) The colours of the cells are more or less the colours of the planets. I guess the Earth was rendered green, because there are already two planets in blue.***

 *) I don't see any indication that the V numeral is related to Venus. The V for five seems to come from an earlier Etruscan number system.
 **) The names of June and July aren't related to Jupiter, but it's hard to find a good reference for everything, so two months beginning with Ju are a good substitute, I guess.
 ***) Useless nerd trivia: TERRA in rot13 is GREEN.

The overall answer ...

 ... is a twelve-letter word that fills the blank in "The ________ Model" to describe the solar system. I suggest HELIOCENTRIC.

Credit where due:

 Stiv solved nearly all of this puzzle: the subdivision of the grid; the identification of the groups and the relevance of the hints; the correlation of the ten boxes to the sun and the planets. I had not seen any of this. (At one point I pondered how an old Fortran routine for rearranging a list according to a list of indices called DPPERM coud figure into this.)

 My only contribution is the observation that the boxes don't represent letters but items that are relevant to the sun and planets. I've now posted this as an answer, but I feel a bit like just sticking a brand logo on a device that was entirely manufactured elsewhere.


Yup this is correct well done. I apologize if this puzzle didn’t meet your standards!

Also I like the transparency… but you did solve the puzzle first nonetheless even if most of the work was not done by you…

Thanks. I don't know about my standards, but I liked the puzzle enough to spend quite some time on it, even if I couldn't get anywhere at first. I guess you refer to my footnotes. They are just quibbles. I don't thinkveeV and jay spoil the puzzle, especially since the other items work quite well, but I thought it worth mentioning. I'm sorry if that cames across as too harsh.

The credits are just some "on shoulders of giants" talk. I still wonder how Stiv got the meaning of the ten boxes from a single element and without seeing the overall connection.

@MOehm A mystery indeed... Especially since the two to the left of the X are obviously related. Still, I shall leave my answer as it was as (what I think is) a good example of a partial answer, albeit one where I could not see the wood for the trees!

Okay, here's a partial answer that attempts to justify that the answer should be:

 The POSTJUDGMENT model. While the word 'postjudgment' usually means 'after a decision', I think that this puzzle is actually an attempt to create an aid for puzzle-solving, i.e. to help one 'judge' a 'post' here on PSE (particularly an enigmatic-puzzle) regarding what its content may relate to.

I say this because...

 ...the grid can be split into six smaller rectangles of a size suggesting a connection to a common list. Especially when combined with the letters given in the hint ("DaPePeElRoMo"), which appear to corroborate the names of these categories.

 See, I think we have:
 - 7 Days of the week,
 - 4 members of an as-yet unknown set whose name begins with 'Pe',
 - 30 members of the lanthanides and actinides section of the Periodic Table,
 - 4 classical Elements (potentially, but I'm not 100% sure)...
 - 7 Roman numerals,
 - 12 Months of the year.

 Additionally, the group at the bottom represents the main elements of our Solar System - the Sun and its planets - with an 'X' in the tenth position to represent the no-longer-classified-as-a-planet Pluto, after whom the element marked with an 'X' in the diagram (Plutonium) is named, suggesting a corroboratory link inside the puzzle.

Like so:

 

 Now, it's possible, mind, that the order of the letters in the given hint might not necessarily match the ordering in the image. Especially since there is an 'I' in the bottom left box which might suggest the Roman numerals should be inserted there in place of the list of days. For now, I have instead assumed it meant 'the first', and therefore listed all groups in order upwards from the bottom (except the Periodic Table group which I have kept in its usual arrangement).

 I am at least confident that I do not yet have this all correct, by any stretch!

How have I obtained this suggested final answer?

 Take the letters corresponding to the coloured boxes in my image - M, S, U, NP, D, O, and a single J - and try to find a 12-letter word that includes all of these (as well as 4 others yet unknown). This led me to POStJUDgMeNt, which seemed a potentially suitable answer.

However, I am sure this suggested solution needs more tinkering with in order to generate the completely correct solution path and answer. More thinking to do...

Well well well. You pretty much got it however there are certain flaws in the interpretation of the grid and how you are to transition from the grid to the next part. Also you are overthinking the last part.

Hint: the colors are significant

As a matter of fact there is really one significant flaw in the interpretation of the grid that if you fix you will get the answer I am sure

I was also going down the letter path, but now I think that rot13(gur uvtuyvtugrq pryyf ner whfg ersreraprf gb gur gra pryyf orybj: Rnegu vf evtug gurer :), Znepu, Fha, Fng, H, Ac, Cg. V thrff Whcvgre vf Wha/Why naq Irahf vf I, nygubhtu Sevqnl (iraqerqv, ivrearf) zvtug unir orra n orggre svg. Vs gung'f gehr, gur terl pryy zhfg or Zrephel. Naq gur nafjre zvtug whfg or "uryvbpragevp", sbe rknzcyr.)

@M Oehm you are right! Please post your interpretation and the checkmark will go to you!

Ah, thanks, but I'd rather wait what Stiv says. He's really solved most of the puzzle. (Also, I'm just about to leave the house.)

@MOehm Very happy for you to post a separate answer when you have time - you've spotted the significance of the colours and managed to find a way to tie it all together. Happy just to be a stepping stone in the process! :)
